# Take data from csv file and plot the graph in jenkins

Tags: jenkins-plugins

```
set -x
echo "counting supresswarning.."
grep -ir  "@SuppressWarning" . > ara.csv
```

I am running this script and strorig the output in CSV file.

Csv file keeps increasing every day, I want to plot the chart. How many rows present in excel for every build?

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. Can you describe what you've tried so far, what that produced, and what you would like to happen?

Comment: I have many . java files in the source. I have to find @supresswaning  word count in the source(almost 100 java files) and also Plot a graph in Jenkins for the count which I have got.